# Истечение подписки

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram

Пишу телеграм бота где будет ежемесячная подписка.

Но как реализовать истечение подписки?

Пример: Пользователь купил подписку на месяц(22.11-22.12) и ему задался статус в бд до 22.12
а по истечению статус пропал

Comment: Ну понятно как. Храните в базе диапазон действия подписки и проверяете текущую дату -  она  попала в диапазон -  значит все в порядке. Она (текущая дата) вышла за диапазон  -  значит подписка истекла.  Неужели это какой-то сверхсложный алгоритм?

Answer (score 1):

В БД хранится дата, до которой действует подписка.

Раз в день (или несколько раз) происходит проверка базы. Если текущая дата больше даты в БД, то что-то делаем (удаляем подписку, меняем статус и т.п.).

Запрос к БД примерно выглядит так:

```
keys = cursor.execute("
SELECT * 
FROM keys 
WHERE end_date < datetime('now') AND key_status = 1")
"
```

В данном случае я получаю ключи, у которых дата просрочена и статус равен 1 (т.е. ключ активный). Соотствественно я меняю статус на 0.

Это у меня так сделано, но вы можете реализовать иначе (не по статусу ключа например, а как-то иначе).

--

Как раз в день (в час и пр.) реализовать проверку? Асинхронно запускать такую задачу. Я это сделал через APScheduler.

(Я тоже пишу бота.)